# How to use matplotlib to plot stress function graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

everyone!
I'm new to python and PyQT.
I want to calculate stress tensor components using this formula

[Stress tensor component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnGjS.jpg)

where lambda, mu, and alpha - are constants, and T - is the change of temperature.

and then plot it using matplotlib, with temperature change on the x-axis, and the change of stress on the y-axis.

I've made a GUI in QT Designer with three buttons, to calculate for different materials. And so far, i am only able to calculate stress at some point of temperature.

But now i'm stuck at plotting, because i've never used matlib for plotting, and i hope you can help me.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic


qtCreatorFile = "Application.ui"

Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)

class MyApp(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.clcbtn.clicked.connect(self.CalculateStress)
    self.clcbtn_2.clicked.connect(self.CalculateStress1)
    self.clcbtn_3.clicked.connect(self.CalculateStress2)


def CalculateStress(self):
   t = int(self.textEdit.toPlainText())
   lam = 55500000000
   theta = 10
   mu = 26100000000
   alpha = 0.0000222
   str11 = 3
   total_stress = lam * theta + 2 * mu * str11 - (3 * lam + 2 * mu) * alpha * t
   total_stress_string = "The total stress is: " + str(total_stress)
   self.results_window.setText(total_stress_string)


def CalculateStress1(self):
   t = int(self.textEdit.toPlainText())
   lam = 104400000000
   theta = 10
   mu = 82000000000
   alpha = 0.000013
   str11 = 5
   total_stress1 = lam * theta + 2 * mu * str11 - (3 * lam + 2 * mu) * alpha * t
   total_stress_string = "The total stress is: " + str(total_stress1)
   self.results_window.setText(total_stress_string)

def CalculateStress2(self):
   t = int(self.textEdit.toPlainText())
   lam = 5450000000
   theta = 10
   mu = 1480000000
   alpha = 0.0000702
   str11 = 3
   total_stress2 = lam * theta + 2 * mu * str11 - (3 * lam + 2 * mu) * alpha * t
   total_stress_string = "The total stress is: " + str(total_stress2)
   self.results_window.setText(total_stress_string)


if __name__ == "__main__":

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MyApp()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: But you seem to be outputting just a number. What do you want to plot (and what kind of plot)? Also where are you plotting it? Do you want the default matplotlib window or an embed one?

Comment: I'd separate the specific question about your stress plotting from the Qt question. See [mcve]. Just split the question into two.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a widget with a FigureCanvas to do so. I can share a customized QWidget of mine, that is based on an example from the [matloplib reference](http://matplotlib.org/).

```
class MplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    """Represents a canvas in QtGui.QWidget"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.fig = Figure()
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)

        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,
                                   QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                                   QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)


class MplWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    """Represents a customized Matplotlib QWidget"""

    def __init__(self):      
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.canvas = MplCanvas()
        self.axes = self.canvas.fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)       
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)

    def draw_array(self, label, a):
        line, = self.axes.plot(a[:,0], a[:,1], label=label)
        self.axes.legend()
        self.resize_subplot(self.axes)
        self.canvas.draw()
```

You can create an instance of that with `myMplWidget = MplWidget()` add this to a layout or use it as centralWidget in your `QMainWindow` with `setCentralWidget(myMplWidget)` and use `myMplWidget.draw_array("My array", arr)`, assuming `arr` is a 2-dimensional array

*Please keep me updated if you won't get the code working. I modified it for this answer and did not test modifications*